# How to make sure clients have enough words in textarea by using angularjs in order to disable/enable a button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to enable a button if the client enters a certain amount of words, but disable it if their word count is not met.

I started simply by using character length instead of words by using an "if" "else" condition, but could not get the desired result. I have used "ng-model" in a textarea element, but every time I refresh the page it always has "true" or "false" in the textarea already typed, and when I delete it, it always enables the button. And when I enter a single character in textarea the button gets disabled.

```
<span ng-controller="pract">
   <textarea id="blogVal" ng-model="btnChange" placeholder="Share"> 
   </textarea>
   <button ng-disabled="btnChange" class="btnpost">Post</button>
</span>
```

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("pract", ($scope) => {    
    $scope.clientValLength = document.getElementById("blogVal").value.length;
    if ($scope.clientValLength <= 7) {
        $scope.btnChange = true;
    } else {
        $scope.btnChange = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at `ng-change`. When there is change to the value, function used in ng-change will be triggered. There you can do your checks.

From your code, seems like you are changing the value of `$scope.btnChange` to true or false. This will affect your textarea value.

And it is not a good practice to use vanilla javascript to retrieve values from DOM. So try to avoid `document.getElementById("blogVal")`

```
<textarea id="blogVal" ng-model="textAreaValue" ng-change="textChange()" placeholder="Share"></textarea>
<button ng-disabled="btnChange" class="btnpost">Post</button>
```

```
$scope.textChange(){
    if ($scope.textAreaValue.split(' ').length<= 7) {
        $scope.btnChange = true;
    } else {
        $scope.btnChange = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: (Just a little plus to sweeten the answer. The rest was already good enough for a +1.)